# How to change part name in TOC only (with babel)? Or How to patch a bug in babel french with amsart

Tags: table-of-contents, babel, amsart, babel-french

When I use `babel` with `french` option and `amsart`, I get the word "partie" in the TOC and not "Partie" which is the correct typographic rule in french (in the main document I get "Première partie" which is ok because "partie" is not the first word so not cap needed).

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Essai}

\end{document}
```

I just want to correct this mistake without using `titletoc` package. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: I'd say there is a bug in `french`, because with your MWE I'm getting Première partie 1. Essai (note the extra ‘1’) and there is an extra space in the toc lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out, babel-french's option `PartNameFull=false` provides a fix: then you get "Partie I", "Partie II" (Roman numerals) both in the document and in the TOC.

In order to get "Première partie" both in the document and in the TOC, you could try something like this:

```
\documentclass[french]{amsart}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
% Patch amsart.cls:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\@seccntformat{#1}}%
                 {\ifx0#2\unskip.\quad\else\@seccntformat{#1}\fi}{}{}
% To get "Première partie." in the TOC:
\renewcommand{\tocpart}[3]{\indentlabel\ignorespaces
   \ifcase#2\or{Première}\or{Deuxième}\or{Troisième}\else{?}\fi
   \space\partnameord.\quad#3}
% To get "Partie 1." in the TOC only, uncomment these two lines:
%\renewcommand{\tocpart}[3]{\indentlabel\ignorespaces
%   Partie\space#2.\quad#3}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Un essai}
\blindtext
\section{test test test}
\blindtext
\part{Second essai}
\end{document}
```

This works for up to three parts, extending the `\tocpart` command is obvious in case you need more.

With `amsbook.cls`, you could use `etoolbox` this way:

```
\documentclass[french]{amsbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}{\ \thepart}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Each class would require a specific treatment, so I just provide the
`PartNameFull=false` option in babel-french to work around this issue.

Comment: Quite an interesting answer. I am tempted to accept it as an answer provided 
1/ there are some nasty side effects for this patch: 1.1/ the numbering of section, subsection and others completely disappear from the main body of my document (but not in the TOC)! It should come from your <\def\@seccntformat#1{\unskip.\quad}> line but I do not know how to change it. 1.2/ I got "Première partie" and so on right in the TOC but in the main body I only got "Partie" without numbering neither "Première Partie". Quite not right.
Could you please try to patch your patch?
 (see next comment)

Comment: (following of my previous comment)
2/ What my neurotic mind really wants is to keep "Première partie" formatting in the main body of my document (but without numbering with ordinals!) and just "Partie" with the corresponding number in the TOC.
Can you please improve your next patch in that direction?

Comment: You are right my patch was too rough. I have just edited my answer. It seems to work now, leaving "Première partie" both in TOC and document.

Comment: Please note that the patch is *not* meant for multilingual documents (French *only*).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Some progress have been made, meaning my point 1.1/ in my comments is dealt with. Yet, point 1.2/ (in the main body, the Part title appears only as "Partie" without numbering neither "Premiere partie") and 2/ (what I really want) remain not adressed. Could you make a patch of the patch of your patch :)?

Comment: Sorry, it works here. Didn't you forget to delete `\frenchsetup{PartNameFull=false}`?

Comment: Yes I did! Now my point 1.2/ has been nicely dealt with thanks also to your patch. Only my point 2/ remains, which is how to have only "Partie"+number in the TOC (and not "partie"). If I understand a bit the logic of your patch, then I should not have to complete by hand the names of the different part in that case (my book has a lots of part!). Could you change a bit your patch to address this?

Comment: This is even easier to achieve: variant added to my answer.

Comment: Excellent job! You got it!

Answer (score 2):

Add in your preamble the code

```
\addto\captionsfrench{% <===============================================
  \renewcommand\partname{Partie}%
}
```

A complete MWE with two parts

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\addto\captionsfrench{% <===============================================
  \renewcommand\partname{Partie}%
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Essai}
\blindtext
\section{test test test}
\blindtext
\part{test part 2}

\end{document}
```

gives you the following result:

[image: resulting toc]

BTW: in the manual of `babel-french` you can find in chapter 1.2.1 \frenchsetup:

[image: manual babel-french]

and please see the red marked text there. The resulting pdf is the same I showed above.

With option `PartNameFull=true` in the mwe above you get the following pdf:

[image: wrong toc and part]

Please see the wrong TOC entries for the parts: It should be `Partie 1` instead `partie 1` or it should be `Première partie` without number.

This bug should be reported to the author of babel-french, e-mail address see the documentation (`texdoc babel-french`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I just want to change the name of part in TOC not in the main document, where I like "Première partie". With your solution it becomes "Partie 1".

Comment: Ok so if I understood well, either I setup the option to True and then I get the double bug (no cap in TOC at the word "partie" and "Première partie 1." in the main body), either I setup the option to False and then I get the word "Partie" in the TOC and the main body (like in your MWE but with no need for your correction) which is typographically correct but lack the elegance of "Première Partie" and so on. A pity!